# Raspbery pi fails writing to memory to initialize the function alt0

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a raspy driver for pin 4.
while setting the alt0 function, raspy hangs, i have to restart it again.

```
#define RPI_DQ_GPIO_PIN 4
#define FUN_ALT0_SET    0x4

ds18b20_gpio_function(RPI_DQ_GPIO_PIN, FUN_ALT0_SET);
```

and

```
extern inline void ds18b20_gpio_function(u8 pin, u16 gpio_fun)
{
    u32 val;

    void __iomem *base_addr = (void __iomem *)(0xf2200000);

    u8 offset = (pin / 10) * 4;
    pin = (pin % 10) * 3;
    val =  gpio_fun << pin;

    printk("ds18b20_gpio_function : pin = %d, val = %x, base_address + offset = %x\n", pin, val, base_addr + offset);

    write_to_reg(val, base_addr + offset);
}
```

and

```
inline void write_to_reg(u32 b, volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "write_to_reg : address = %x, b = %ld\n", addr, b);
    __raw_writel(b, addr);
    mb();
}
```

I got this virtual address of ioremap after dmesged of default gpio driver.
How can i solve it ?
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks,

Comment: Huh? This is pinctrl area of interest. Why do you need to touch controller registers yourself?

Comment: I would like to learn the internal structure of the code flow. So is there any way to do that ... ???

Comment: don't I  have other option. cant i disable default driver and enable this new module in DT

Comment: It will barely work normal without pinctrl driver in place.

Comment: why I am not able to write configs on memory .... ???does it have memory protection ... ??? can you please suggest me alternate way .., ?

Comment: Because you have to understand the difference between `physical`, `virtual`, and `bus` address name spaces. Looking at your code seems you have no clue about memory barriers.